# Laravel not returning error messages when there is more then 12 validation rules

Tags: laravel, validation, error-messaging

ok this is messed up... there is a simple form with 20 inputs. I'm submitting this form with no values. and my custom validation rules are all "required" . so i want it to show me errors . but the thing is . out of 20 rules any 12 rules work (in random) . as soon as I add 13th rule it stops returning error messages.

//// this is the form ////

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{route('addschoolbranchindb')}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="col-xl-12 order-xl-1 mt-5">
            <div class="card bg-secondary shadow">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Add School Branch</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 text-right">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ count($errors)}}
                    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">School information</h6>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold; width:100%" class="" for="fk_school_id">Select School</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative fk_school_id" id="fk_school_id" name="fk_school_id">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    @foreach ($schools as $school)
                                        <option value="{{$school->school_id}}">{{$school->school_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('fk_school_id')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="sc_br_name">Branch Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="sc_br_name" name="sc_br_name" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Branch Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('sc_br_name')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="sc_br_address">School Address</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="sc_br_address" name="sc_br_address" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="School Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('sc_br_address')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="sc_br_status">School status</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative sc_br_status" id="sc_br_status" name="sc_br_status">
                                    <option value="1">Un-Registered</option>
                                    <option value="2">Under Process</option>
                                    <option value="3">Registered</option>
                                    {{-- @foreach ($schools as $school)
                                        <option value="{{$school->school_id}}">{{$school->school_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach --}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('sc_br_status')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="no_of_boys">No of Boys</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="no_of_boys" name="no_of_boys" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Number of Boys">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('no_of_boys')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="no_of_girls">No of Girls</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="no_of_girls" name="no_of_girls" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Number of girls">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('no_of_girls')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="sc_br_covered_area">Covered Area</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="sc_br_covered_area" name="sc_br_covered_area" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Total Covered Area">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('sc_br_covered_area')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="no_of_teachers">No of Teachers</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="no_of_teachers" name="no_of_teachers" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Number Of Teachers">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('no_of_teachers')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="my-4" />

                    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Owner information</h6>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="owner_name">Owner Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="owner_name" name="owner_name" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Owner Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('owner_name')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="owner_phone">Owner Phone No</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" id="owner_phone" name="owner_phone" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Owner Number">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('owner_phone')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="owner_email">Owner Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="owner_email" name="owner_email" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Owner Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('owner_email')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="my-4" />

                    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Principal information</h6>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="principal_name">Principal Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="principal_name" name="principal_name" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Principal Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('principal_name')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="principal_phone">Principal Phone No</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input type="text" id="principal_phone" name="principal_phone" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Principal Number">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('principal_phone')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="principal_email">Principal Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="principal_email" name="principal_email" class="disable_on_sc_id form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Principal Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('principal_email')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr class="my-4" />

                    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Area information</h6>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="pov_for_subarea">Select Province</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative pov_for_subarea" id="pov_for_subarea" name="pov_for_subarea">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    @foreach ($provinces as $province)
                                        <option value="{{$province->province_id}}">{{$province->province_name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="city_for_subarea">Select City</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative city_for_subarea" id="city_for_subarea" name="city_for_subarea">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="areaselect">Select Area</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative areaselect" id="areaselect" name="areaselect">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="fk_subarea_id">Select Sub-Area</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative fk_subarea_id" id="fk_subarea_id" name="fk_subarea_id">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="latitude">Latitude</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input  type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" class="form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Latitude">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('latitude')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="longitude">Longitude</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input  type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" class="form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Longitude">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('longitude')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label style="font-weight:bold" class="" for="location_string">Location String</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input  type="text" id="location_string" name="location_string" class="form-control form-control-alternative" 
                                placeholder="Location String">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @error('location_string')
                                        <span class="ml-auto mr-auto" style="color:red">{{$message}}</span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

//// this is the controller ////

```
public function addSchoolBranchInDb(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        $rules = [
            'fk_school_id' => 'required',
            'sc_br_name' => 'required',
            'sc_br_address' => 'required',
            'sc_br_status' => 'required',
            'no_of_boys' => 'required',
            'no_of_girls' => 'required',
            'sc_br_covered_area' => 'required',
            'no_of_teachers' => 'required',
            'owner_name' => 'required',
            'owner_phone' => 'required',
            'owner_email' => 'required',
            'principal_name' => 'required',
            // 'principal_phone' => 'required',
            // 'principal_email' => 'required',
            // 'fk_subarea_id' => 'required',
            // 'latitude' => 'required',
            // 'longitude' => 'required',
            // 'location_string' => 'required',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'fk_school_id.required' => 'School Name is required',
            'sc_br_name.required' => 'School Branch Name is required',
            'sc_br_address.required' => 'School Address is required',
            'sc_br_status.required' => 'School Status is required',
            'no_of_boys.required' => 'Number of boys is required',
            'no_of_girls.required' => 'Number of girls is required',
            'sc_br_covered_area.required' => 'School covered area is required',
            'no_of_teachers.required' => 'Number of teachers is required',
            'owner_name.required' => 'Owner Name is required',
            'owner_phone.required' => 'Owner Phone is required',
            'owner_email.required' => 'Owner Email is required',
            'principal_name.required' => 'Principal Name is required',
            'principal_phone.required' => 'Principal Phone is required',
            'principal_email.required' => 'Principal Email is required',
            'fk_subarea_id.required' => 'Subarea is required',
            'latitude.required' => 'Latitude is required',
            'longitude.required' => 'Longitude is required',
            'location_string.required' => 'Location String is required',
        ];
        $validator = validator::make($request->all() , $rules );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        $sc_branch = new Schoolbranch;
        $sc_branch->fill($request->all());     
        $sc_branch->save();                                                                                                       
        Session::flash('message','School Branch is added');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success'); 
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: is better create `request` and call on `controller` see docs

Comment: did that too not working

Comment: This is a weird one, however it might be because the data is too big to put in your session and it silently fails because of that. The default session driver is `cookie` for Laravel try changing the driver to `file` (in `config/session.php`), clear your cookies (the `file` driver still uses cookies) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok yes I got the answer from laracast. Alex bouma's answer is right . Just change driver session to file. It works – Tallal just now